# Dynamic imports in ES6 with runtime variables

Tags: ecmascript-6, dynamic-import

Recently stumbled upon the [dynamic import proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) and also this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eg8eLH52d4s) . Thought would be a great idea to use it for on demand imports of components in React.

Running into  an issue where I was not able to "resolve" a path when `import` is passed  string literals as runtime variables.

for eg:

```
<div>
  <button onClick={this._fetchComp.bind(this, "../component/Counter")}>Get Async Comp</button>
</div>
```

Tried with multiple options for _fetchComp, but passing parameters doesnt seem to work . A breakdown of the different options tried.

1. **Template Strings** *Does Not Work* : Getting an the below error on click

> Error: Cannot find module '../components/Counter'.  at
> webpackAsyncContext (^.*$:53)

**Code**

```
    _fetchComp(res) {
    import(`${res}`).then(() => {
        console.log("Loaded")
    },(err)=>{
        console.log("Error",err)
    })}
```

2. **Variabes** *Doesn't work*: Getting an error during webpack build as 55:12-23

> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

```
**Code**

    _fetchComp(res) {
    import(res).then(() => {
        console.log("Loaded")
    },(err)=>{
        console.log("Error",err)
    })}
```

3. **String literal** *Works* : Just passing pure string literals . On click i am able to see the chunk being downloaded in the dev tools Network tab

   **Code**

   ```
   _fetchComp(res) {
   import("../components/Counter").then(() => {
       console.log("Loaded")
   },(err)=>{
       console.log("Error",err)
   })}
   ```

As per the spec,

> import() accepts arbitrary strings (with runtime-determined template
> strings shown here), not just static string literals.

So I was hoping the string literal will do the part, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I came across a similar issue on [flow issue tracker](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3850). But the proposed solution advocated use of string literals again.

I'll leave you all with a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3yxkq5wjm1)  link.

Comment: Well, it's only a proposal (and definitely not ES6!), what makes you think that webpack would already support it? Also it would require a client side setup that does support dynamic module loading.

Comment: @Bergi  : "webpack would already support it" - Ah was worried about this ! :(  . And i did the trials with the `create-react-app` thingy locally, isn't  that a good client side setup to hack around with dynamic imports?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The rules for `import()` for the spec are not the same rules for Webpack itself to be able to process `import()`. For Webpack to handle an import, it needs to be able to at least guess roughly what an `import()` is meant to be referencing.

This is why your example of `import("../components/Counter")` works, because Webpack can be 100% confident in what needs to be loaded.

For *your* usecase, you could for instance do

```
_fetchComp(res) {
  import(`../components/${res}`).then(() => {
    console.log("Loaded")
  }, (err)=>{
    console.log("Error", err)
  })
}
```

with

```
this._fetchComp.bind(this, "Counter")
```

and now that Webpack knows that the path starts with `../components/`, it can bundle up *every* component automatically and then load the one you need. The downside here is that because it doesn't know which component you're loading, it has to load them all and there's no guarantee they are all actually being used. That is the tradeoff of dynamic imports.

Comment: I noticed that if one uses `import(\`../components/${res}\`)` the webpack bundles also the css files in semi-random order, causing a terrible mess.

Comment: @Ciantic Then consider doing ```import(`../components/${res}.js`)``` so Webpack knows you will only be loading JS files.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I was working on dynamic dashboard functionality, I was stuck for long time, But your solution worked great. Adding "pages/" to the dynamic importing worked. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this! I was struggling for ages!!