# Image load in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-image

I am uploading less code because I think it is enoug
 Ask if need more to find error

```
async componentDidMount(){


var image = this.props.data.img
console.log(this.props.data.img == './../images/thumbnails/g.png') // true
console.log(this.props.data.img === './../images/thumbnails/g.png') // true
console.log(typeof(this.props.data.img))
await import(image)
            .then((res)=>{
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({img:res})
            })
            .catch((e)=>{
                console.log(this.props.data.img)
                console.log(e)
            })
}
```

I am trying to import image.

When i use `import('./../images/thumbnails/g.png)` then it run successfully but when i pass same value as props and tries to import that then it through error (module not found).
I log the values and all are coming out to be true that mean string and string by props are same then why i am getting 2 different behavior?

Comment: You can't import the file by passing string as variable to `import`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47956054/7232300

Comment: Basically when your module bundler is bundling your application at that time value of `this.props.data.img` is not available because that value is only available during runtime (i.e. after bundling).

Answer (score 0):

You should install the `file-loader` on your application, then use the image in your jsx/js/css files.

to install `file-loader` use below command:

> npm install file-loader --save-dev

And update your `webpack` by following code:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then import your file

```
import img from './file.png'
```

For loading Images based on props you can do these ways:

```
<img src={require(this.props.name)} alt=''/>
```

or

```
<img src={require('../assets/images/yourimage.png')} alt=''/>
```

or

```
<img src={require(`../assets/images/${this.props.name.toLowerCase()}.png`)}/>
```

Comment: I am successfully loading images on site but not able to do same when pass image path string value as props. I have set file-loader and it is working fine

Comment: I need to use `<img src={require(this.props.name)} alt=''/>` but it is throwing error **Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."** and this is actually a different string