# Dynamic path import for lazy loading of components using react-loadable

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, code-splitting, react-loadable

I am creating an app using create-react-app and lazy loading the component using react-loadable.

What I want to do is import dynamic paths for the loader object or the Loadable function of react-loadble module.

Code:

```
const LoadableComponent = path =>
 Loadable({
  loader: () => import(`${path}`),
  loading: Loader,
 })

const Home = LoadableComponent('./../../pages/Home')
const User = LoadableComponent('./../../pages/User')
```

If I put the path string in the place of the path variable (Ex. import('./pages/Home')) and call the function it works. But when I use it like the code above Loader will load but it will not continue to load the component anymore. Why doesn't it work if I use the variable in import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954655/dynamic-imports-in-es6-with-runtime-variables)

*"For Webpack to handle an import, it needs to be able to at least guess roughly what an import() is meant to be referencing."*

Turns out your path cannot be too anonymous. Guess it is stacked to deep for Webpack to confidently know what I am importing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the bundler (Webpack) needs to be able to process the file path upfront.

My question would be why is it required? Is there anything so bad about just writing?

```
const Home = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./pages/Home'),
  loading: Loader,
})

const User = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./pages/User'),
  loading: Loader,
})
```

Bonus point: Take a look at [new React's `lazy` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html), recently release in 16.6. The linked page also has some good information on code splitting.

Comment: Sorry. I just don't think it will be very efficient to do with multiple pages. Also I was planning to use it to multiple files but I guess it would be impossible to do unless they aren't stacked too deep for webpack to locate. Also my react is 16.5 so .lazy isn't included yet.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify config lazy loading,the solution likes below:

```
import React, {Component, lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
let routers={
    '/about': import('./pages/about'),
    '/contact':  import('./pages/contact'),
}

class Content() extends Component{
   render(){
     return (<Switch>
        {Object.keys(this.props.routers).map((path, idx) => {
            let Child = lazy(()=>this.props.routers[path])
            return (
                <Route path={path} key={idx}>
                    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                        <Child></Child>
                    </Suspense>
                </Route>)
        })}
    </Switch>
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/about"> About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <Content routers={config.routers}></Content>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    ),
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
)
```