# React lazy import can't import the component if use string varibale

Tags: reactjs, template-literals

In my project I have a component render the child node according to the current URL, it uses the `React.lazy` to import the children components. I implement it followed this [post answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847745/react-dynamic-render-with-path-by-props-value) code example.

I noticed a strange thing when I implement it, if I import the component using template strings like the following code shows, it works fine.

`` const Lzy = React.lazy(() => import(`${currentConfig.componentPath}`)); ``

But when I import the components using the variable directly, it always has an error message on the web pages.

`const Lzy = React.lazy(() => import(currentConfig.componentPath));`

---

Error Message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './home/order/OrderForm'
(anonymous function)
src/features lazy groupOptions: {} namespace object:5
```

---

The array of `currentConfig` object

```
const pathConfig = [{path: "/dashboard/order/new", componentPath: './home/order/OrderForm'}]
```

---

Code snippet

```
    const [CurrentChild, setCurrentChild] = useState(() => () => <div>loading...</div>)
useEffect(() => {
    let currentConfig = pathConfig.find(item => item.path === currentPath)
    if (!!currentConfig) {
        const Lzy = React.lazy(() => import(currentConfig.componentPath));
        //const Lzy = React.lazy(() => import(`${currentConfig.componentPath}`));
        setCurrentChild(Lzy)
    }
}, [currentPath])
```

Why the first one can work but the second has the can't find the module error, any difference between these two lines code, anyone can help on this?

Comment: See [How do I dynamically import images in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192731/2873538). You can also write `const Lzy = React.lazy(() => import(currentConfig.componentPath + ''));` which would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use in that way, You can refer ECMA Doc https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-imports

> *ImportDeclaration :*
>
> - **import** ImportClause FromClause ;
> - **import** ModuleSpecifier ;
>
> *FromClause :*
>
> - **from** ModuleSpecifier
>
> *ModuleSpecifier :*
>
> - from ModuleSpecifier

*A ModuleSpecifier can only be a StringLiteral, not any other kind of expression like an AdditiveExpression.*