# Cannot seem to use a JavaScript variable in require for dynamic import in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-google-maps but I think my question applies a general user case.
I want to dynamically load an icon, using a url passed in as a prop. But I find if I use a variable I get an error.  Please see below:

When I require and icon using a string it works fine e.g.

```
icon={require('../assets/myPng.png')}
```

But if my png path is a variable for example

```
let url = '../assets/myPng.png'

icon={require(`${url)`}
```

I get error:

> cannot find module '../assets/myPng.png'

Can anyone tell me what is going on ?

if I use `icon={require(url}`, that fails also.

Comment: Might be worth looking into [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954655/dynamic-imports-in-es6-with-runtime-variables) if you want to have dynamic imports.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `require(...)`, so the path will be managed by your package manager. If you use directly a string, it will bypass it, and you will get the error. I would advise to use:

```
const icon = require('../assets/myPng.png')
// ...
<MapComponent icon={icon} ... />
```

Comment: why not just `const { icon } = require('../assets/myPng.png');` ?

Comment: Because `require(...)` usually returns a string when used on a picture, not an object. You will get `undefined` here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments , but I need to have the require(...) use a variable and to dynamically load the icon depending on the user,  I cannot use hardcode a string . I see npm dynamic-import and will try that , but from more investigation it seems impossible to dynamically require something in the way I want - unfortunately I cannot use import.

Comment: Well, import can be used dynamically, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports