# Vue 2 dynamic component import issue

Tags: vue.js

I have dynamic component called like this:

```
<component v-bind:is="loaderComponent" />
```

Then in my export default:

```
export default {
components: {
    'loader': () => import(Vue.prototype.$VUE_LOADER_CONFIG.componentUrl)
  }
},
computed: {
    loaderComponent: function () {
    console.log('1', Vue.prototype.$VUE_LOADER_CONFIG.componentUrl)
    return 'loader'
  }
}
```

That one console.log gives me the right path to the component, but it doesnt work, i need to pass the string instead of this variable to the import function to make this works.

```
import('../../Loaders/SomeLoader')
```

I get an error:

```
Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function loader() {
      return __webpack_require__("./src/base/components/Payment/Loader lazy recursive")(vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["default"].prototype.$VUE_LOADER_CONFIG.componentUrl);
    }
Reason: Error: Cannot find module '../../Loaders/SomeLoader'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Vue.prototype.$VUE_LOADER_CONFIG.componentUrl` contains a relative path. Try to use an absolute path instead:

```
Vue.prototype.$VUE_LOADER_CONFIG.componentUrl = '@/base/components/Payment/Loader'
```

Comment: Absolute path like this: ```'@/base/components/Payment/Loader'``` gives mi the same error

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954655/dynamic-imports-in-es6-with-runtime-variables